# Mount hibernated Windows partition

Tags: linux, mount, multi-boot, hibernate, fstab

I am trying to mount my Windows partition at boot. It works fine when Windows is in shutdown, but when Windows is hibernated, it can't be mounted as read/write, and I am sent to the root shell at boot. I tried to solve this by adding `errors=remount-ro` to my [fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab), to mount it read-only if it can't be mounted as read/write when it is hibernated, but it doesn't work, and I still get an error at boot.

Is there a way to work around this and boot the partition as read/write when possible, but as read-only when it is hibernated?

```
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1f026730-1640-42fa-b5f6-eca9749b3a98 /boot ext4 defaults 0 2
UUID=2b5c372b-d6d5-4c27-9c3f-5e26ca84d3a7 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
UUID=2c154114-4898-45e6-8455-575e910d8382 / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=92041326-03a7-4fdc-9211-c060e83d662e swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=A28034F38034CF91 /media/win7 ntfs defaults,user,exec,dev,suid,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up removing the line from `/etc/fstab`. I now mount the Windows partition in `~/.xinitrc`, by using the return code from `mount`:

```
# Mount windows
sudo mount -o defaults,user,exec,dev,suid /dev/sda1 /media/win7
if [ $? -eq 14 ]
then
  sudo mount -o defaults,user,exec,dev,suid,ro /dev/sda1 /media/win7
fi
```

To be warned/informed about the way the partition is mounted, I also added the following to my [Conky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29) configuration:

```
/dev/sda1 (Windows) is mounted:
${if_match "${exec mount | grep /dev/sda1 | grep -Eo [^a-z]ro[^a-z] | grep -o ro}" == "ro"}${font bold}${alignc}READ-ONLY: WATCH OUT!!!
${else}${alignc}R/W (normal)
${endif}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is ntfs-3g installed?
The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.ntfs-3g) says:

> Unlike in case of read-only mount, the read-write mount is denied if
>   the NTFS volume is hibernated. One needs either to resume Windows and
>   shutdown it properly, or use this option which will remove the Windows
>   hibernation file. Please note, this means that the saved Windows
>   session will be completely lost. Use this option under your own
>   responsibility.

So if you want to mount with read-write ability you have to remove the hibernate file with **remove_hiberfile**.
I also remember using the **force** option to mount that partition anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to remove the hiber file to mount it rw, I said that in the question. But I am looking for a solution where I don't have to remove it, and where it is mounted r/w when possible, but r/o when it is hibernated.

Comment: But I didn't know about the remove_hiberfile option, so if nothing else comes up I'm afraid I'll have to use that.

Comment: If it's an microsoft ntfs drive, you have to play by their rules!

Comment: I don't think you want to use the remove_hiberfile option. I'm fairly certain that using it left my drive in an unsafe state and lead to an irrecoverably damaged Win7 installation. There wasn't any other change that I can remember before it happened that could have been blamed, but I can be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ntfs-3g driver that is refusing to mount the partition in write mode, unless one removes the hibernation file.

Without discussing whether it is a good idea to circumvent it, you could try to use
another driver, such as the free [Paragon NTFS&HFS for Linux 8.5 Express](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-linux-professional/download.html)
(registration required).

You might need to uninstall or disable ntfs-3g for this to work,
but uninstallation is not guaranteed to work (or be easy to reinstall again).
Better do the testing on a Linux system that can be restored in case of error.